# Python: BeautifulSoup extract all the h1 text from div class

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = get('https://www.ceda.com.au/Events/Upcoming-events')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")


event_location = '\n'.join([' '.join(item.find_parent().select("span")[0].text.split()) for item in soup.select(".side-list .icon-map-marker")])
print(event_location)


event_date = '\n'.join([' '.join(item.find_parent().select("span")[0].text.split()) for item in soup.select(".side-list .icon-calendar")])
print(event_date)


event_name = '\n'.join([' '.join(item.find_parent().select("class")[0].text.split()) for item in soup.select(".event-detail-bx .h1")])
print(event_name)
```

I'm trying to extract the **event date,location** and **event name** from the website, I successed in getting event date, Event hyperlink and locaion inforamtion.

But I failed to extract the **Event Name** information, Can some one help me in extracting all the Event names and hyderlinks of each event?

Comment: the reason is not working is because the "*dot*" is for selecting classes names... try something else, maybe find next sibling (times two) or find children... from the "event name"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would like to give this a shot to get all the data in a slightly organized manner:

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.ceda.com.au/Events/Upcoming-events'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")

for items in soup.select(".list-bx"):
    event_name = ''.join([item.text for item in items.select(".event-detail-bx a h1")])
    event_links = urljoin(url,''.join([item['href'] for item in items.select(".event-detail-bx a")]))
    speaker_info = items.select(".sub-content-txt h3")[0].next_sibling.strip()
    event_date = ''.join([' '.join(item.find_parent().select("span")[0].text.split()) for item in items.select(".icon-calendar")])
    event_location = ''.join([' '.join(item.find_parent().select("span")[0].text.split()) for item in items.select(".icon-map-marker")])     
    print("Name: {}\nLink: {}\nSpeaker: {}\nDate: {}\nLocation: {}\n".format(event_name,event_links,speaker_info,event_date,event_location))
```

Partial Output:

```
Name: 2018 Trustee welcome back
Link: https://www.ceda.com.au/Events/Library/Q180124
Speaker: Melinda Cilento, Chief Executive, CEDA
Date: 24/01/2018
Location: Brisbane Convention and Exhibition Centre

Name: NSW Trustee welcome back 2018
Link: https://www.ceda.com.au/Events/Library/N180130
Speaker: Luke Foley MP, NSW Opposition Leader, Parliament of NSW
Date: 30/01/2018
Location: Shangri-La Hotel
```

Comment: Thanks Shahin it's solved my problem, I'm trying to extract Speaker name of all the events but I'm unable to extract the speaker names by this code : "speaker_name = '\n'.join([item.text for item in soup.select(".sub-content-txt h3")]) print(speaker_name) Can you please help me with this ?

Comment: This is my first project i'm working on, Thanks for helping me understad and solving my problem

Comment: Acknowledgement: Every single technique I've used here, I've learnt from sir Andersson.

Comment: Is there by any means I can extract the hydeprlink of the event name ?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code to get required data:

```
event_name = '\n'.join([item.text for item in soup.select(".event-detail-bx h1")])
print(event_name)
```

P.S. Note that CSS selector `.event-detail-bx .h1` means *return node that has class name "h1" which is descendant of the node with class name "event-detail-bx"*. While if you want to get *h1 node that is descendant of the node with class name "event-detail-bx"* you need to use `.event-detail-bx h1`

Comment: Thanks Andersson in helping me understand, This solved my problem

Comment: @ Andersson is there any way I can extract the hyperlink of the event?

Comment: @Mahesh , Please create new ticket regarding this new issue